# Hide an item dynamic depending by a condition

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create something similar to an accordeon:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-golick-xrvt5?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const items = [
    {
      title: "lorem1",
      content: "content1"
    },
    {
      title: "lorem2",
      content: "content2"
    }
  ];
  const [hide, setHide] = useState({
    title: "",
    open: false
  });

  const hideContent = (title) => {
    setHide({
      title: title,
      open: !hide.open
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((i) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1 onClick={() => hideContent(i.title)}>{i.title}</h1>
            {hide.title === i.title && hide.open ? <p>{i.content}</p> : ""}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now when i click on a title its content appears, but when click on another title the first content disappear but the actual clicked does not appear. How to click on the second title and to hide the previous content and in the same time to open the actual clicked item content?

Comment: You need to remove `hide.open` for opening click content i.e `{hide.title === i.title ? <p>{i.content}</p> : ""}`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, but in this way i can't close all items

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, do you know another solution?

Comment: yes updated in answer

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of going with `open` state. Go with `id`. You item state

```
 const items = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "lorem1",
      content: "content1"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "lorem2",
      content: "content2"
    }
  ];
```

Pass id in `hideContent`:

```
const hideContent = (title, id) => {
    setHide(
      (prev) =>
         ({
          title: title,
          open: prev.open === id ? null : id
        })
    );
  }
```

and condition to check inside `return` like this:

```
hide.title === i.title && hide.open === i.id ? (
              <p>{i.content}</p>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
```

here is demo and full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-brattain-8yfx7?file=/src/App.js